# Diffeomorphic but not isotopic symplectic forms

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology

Do we know of any closed symplectic manifold $M$ with 2 cohomologous symplectic forms $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ such that there exist $\psi \in \text{Diff}(M)$ and $\psi^* \omega_1 = \omega_2$ but $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are not isotopic?

Here the word isotopy is supposed to mean that the two forms a joined by a path of cohomologous symplectic forms.

Comment: Take $M = \mathbb R^2, \omega_1 = \mathrm dx\wedge \mathrm dy, \psi(x,y) = (x,-y)$ so that $\omega_2 = -\omega_1$. Since the two symplectic forms induce opposite orientations, they can't be isotopic.

Comment: Ah!  That was silly of me. Thank you for pointing it out. I've edited the question now asking for examples of closed manifolds.

Comment: Doesn't the same style of counterexample still work? Take a closed oriented 2-manifold, let $\omega_1$ be some volume form and $\psi$ an orientation reversing diffeomorphism. For example, take the antipode map on $S^2$.

Comment: If $M$ is a closed surface, volume forms inducing different orientations will not be cohomologous. I think the example in the following answer: https://mathoverflow.net/a/34249/35687 together with the Moser trick to relate the two notions of being isotopic should give a counterexample, though.

Comment: Ah, my bad, I didn't see the condition that the classes are cohomologous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is an extension of my last comment, which in turn is just a reference to [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/34249/35687) by MO user Petya, and the paper [Symplectic Topology and Capacities](http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~dusa/princerev98.pdf) by McDuff cited therein.

First, your condition for two forms to be isotopic is equivalent to the existence of a path of diffeomorphisms $\phi_t$ such that $\phi_{0} = \operatorname{id},\phi_1^*\omega_2 = \omega_1$. One direction is clear; in the other, let $\omega_t$ be the family of symplectic forms and define a time-dependent vector field $X_t$ by $\mathrm d\left(\iota_{X_t}\omega_t\right) = \partial_t\omega_t$ (by assumption, the RHS is exact). The flow of $X_t$, which exists by compactness, is the required family of diffeomorphisms.

Take $M = S^2\times S^2\times T^2$, with $T^2 = S^1\times S^1$ the torus, and let $\omega_1 = p_1\omega_{S^2} + p_2^*\omega_{S^2} + p_3^*\omega_{T^2}$ where $\omega_{S^2}$ and $\omega_{T^2}$ are volume forms on $S^2$ and $T^2$, respectively. (Note that we use the same volume form for both factors of $S^2$.) Let $\psi(x,y,u,v) = (x,R(x,v)y,u,v)$, where $R:S^2\times S^1\to SO(3)$ sends $(x,v)$ to the rotation by $v$ around the axis through $x$. For fixed $y_0,u_0$, the map $x,v\mapsto (x,y_0,u_0,v)$ defines an $S^1$-family of $J$-holomorphic spheres for the product complex structure, and the projection of this family to the second $S^2$-factor si constant. Since each of these spheres has minimal positive area, there is no bubbling, so that for any deformation one obtains a compact cobordism between this family and its pushforward under the end of the deformation. In particular, the projection of the pushforward to the second factor is bordant to a constant map. But one can check that the map $f: S^2\times S^1\to S^2,(x,v)\mapsto R(x,v)y_0$ is not bordant to a constant map: Its restriction to $S^2\vee S^1$ is nullhomotopic, and the resulting map $S^2\times S^1/(S^2\vee S^1)\cong S^3\to S^2$ is homotopic to the Hopf map, which is not nullbordant.

Comment: The link in the answer no longer works - here is a link [to Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20161011140931/http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~dusa/princerev98.pdf).